# Mongoose creating new Mongo database instead of connecting to existing one in Express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working through a Mongo/Express tutorial and have run across a situation that I do not understand.

- I have a MongoDB set up on my local machine.
- I created a new database on my local called myapi `use myapi`
- I added a collection `db.something.insert({...})`
- I can view this data in the mongo command line `db.something.find()`
- I created a very basic Express API. (code below)

Using mongoose I am (seemingly) able to connect to the database I just created. I can add, edit, delete, and read data using the API and Postman -- **However**, It seems to be a completely different database than the one I created on my local. I cannot fetch the data I added through the mongo command line in my API. And in command line, I cannot fetch data that I added using the Express API.

Can someone help explain what I am missing?

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose   = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var router = require('./routes/router.js');

// initialize api and configure to get data from POST
var api = express();
api.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
api.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000; 

// connect to DB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/myapi');

// register routes
api.use('/', router);

// start server
api.listen(port);
console.log('server started on port ' + port);
```

Comment: If you change `127.0.01` to `localhost` do you have the same problem? The only thing I can think of is you [changed your host file](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/).

Comment: @ThisClark Thanks for the suggestion. I tried switching the path to localhost and checked my hosts file for any entries that may be interfering. No changes in behavior.

Comment: Could it be something in the way the Mongo db is configured? perhaps `127.0.0.1:some-other-port`?

Comment: Mongodb default port is 27017